# Non-test TypeScript files not processed by TS-Jest. Cannot find module with absolute path during runtime

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a project with E2E tests setup with Playwright + TS-Jest. To organize my tests I use Page Object Model. Structure looks like that:

[image]

I wanted to use TypeScript `paths` option in `tsconfig.json` to clean up the imports both in test files as well as in POM classes. After some trial and error I came up with the following config files:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmit": true,
        "types": ["@types/jest", "jest-playwright-preset"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "models": ["models"],
            "models/*": ["models/*"],
            "config": ["../config"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

```js
// jest.config.ts
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';
import playwrightPreset from 'jest-playwright-preset/jest-preset.json';

import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    ...playwrightPreset,
    testRunner: 'jasmine2',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        ...playwrightPreset.setupFilesAfterEnv,
    ],
    testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|js)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
        prefix: '<rootDir>/src',
    }),
};
```

The imports like

```js
// src/tests/home.test.ts
import { baseUrl, username, password } from 'config';
import { LoginPage, CookiesModal, NavbarComponent, SurveyEditPage } from 'models';
```

work correctly in test files and don't cause any trouble. Problems appear when I try to use them in any of the other files, ex.

```js
// src/global-setup.ts
import type { Config as JestConfig } from '@jest/types';
import { chromium, Page } from 'playwright';
import { username, password } from 'config';
import { CookiesModal, LoginPage } from './models';
```

Although TypeScript doesn't complain about anything in Visual Studio Code, when running the tests with `yarn test` I got an error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'config'
```

I think it looks like the other TS files are not processed by TS-Jest or anything else. I might be completely wrong though. Any solutions highly appreciated

Comment: can you help to provide github repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find solution in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1107#issuecomment-559759395

In short, by default `ts-jest` transform is invoked later than it should, so doesn't have a chance to process all the files. The [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) can help with that:

1. Install above package with `yarn add --dev tsconfig-paths`
2. In `global-setup` file add `require('tsconfig-paths/register');` at the very beginning of the file.

All the absolute imports should work.